# How to count multiple buttons after pressed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

My program creates a Periodic Table of Elements and after clicking on an element, information about the selected element is given. There are 2 additional buttons.

1. Reset - erases loaded information and displays the generic message.
2. Play - generates a random element, how many guesses it took, and checks if the selected element by the player matches.

I have a problem with adding up how many guesses it took. I think it's because the buttons get created in a different function. So I tried to look up how to access a variable from a different function but I couldn't fit any solution to my program.

The checking system also does not work. I was thinking if I could make it a separate function that could help. I'll get to it tomorrow but I'll be happy for any kind of help.

Here is the full program. 5 individual files.

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
import json

class PeriodicTable(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        '''Initializes a new instance of the PeriodicTable class'''

        self.default_title = "Periodická tabulka prvků"
        self.default_header = "Klikněte na prvek pro zobrazení víc informací."
        self.reset_button_text = "Reset"
        self.play_button_text = "Play"
        self.button_clicks = 0

        # get data for building the elements table
        self.elements_data = self.get_elements_data()
        self.elements_map = self.get_elements_map()
        self.elements_color_map = self.get_elements_color_map()

        # add controls on UI
        self.buttons = {}
        self.parent = parent
        self.winfo_toplevel().title(self.default_title)
        self.topLabel = tk.Label(self, text=self.default_header, font=('Times', 40))
        self.topLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=18)
        self.build_elements_table()
        self.infoLine = tk.Label(self, text="", justify='left', font=('Helvetica bold',20))
        self.infoLine.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=10, rowspan=4)
        self.reset_button = tk.Button(self, text=self.reset_button_text, width=5, height=2, bg= "#124f3a", fg = "white",
                                      command=lambda text="": (self.change_header(self.default_header), self.change_info("")))
        self.reset_button.grid(row=13, column=0)
        self.play_button = tk.Button(self, text=self.play_button_text, width=5, height=2, bg= "#2b239a", fg = "white",
                                      command=lambda: self.game_body())
        self.play_button.grid(row=13, column=18)

    def get_elements_data(self):
        with open('elements.json') as file:
            return json.loads(file.read())

    def get_elements_map(self):
        with open('elements_layout_map.json') as file:
            return json.loads(file.read())

    def get_elements_color_map(self):
        with open('color_map.json') as file:
            return json.loads(file.read())

    def build_elements_table(self):
        '''Adds button controls for each element on UI'''
        for element in self.elements_data["elements"]:
            name = element["Short"]
            row = self.elements_map["map"][name]["row"]
            col = self.elements_map["map"][name]["column"]
            color = self.elements_color_map['map'][element["Categories"][0]]
            def get_info(element):
                return "Protonove cislo = {}\nAtomova hmotnost = {}\nSkupenstvi = {}\nSkupina = {}".format(
                       element['Atomic Number'],
                       element['Atomic Weight'],
                       element['State'],
                       element['Categories'][0])
            button = tk.Button(self, text=name, bg=color,
                               command=lambda  e=element: (self.change_header(e["Name"]), self.change_info(get_info(e))))
            button.config(width = 12, height= 4)
            button.grid(row=row, column=col,sticky="NSEW")            
            self.buttons[name] = button
        self.fillerLine = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.fillerLine.grid(row=10, column=0)

    def change_header(self, text):
        self.topLabel.config(text=text)

    def change_info(self, text):
        self.infoLine.config(text=text)

    def game_body(self):
        with open('game.json') as base:
            data = json.load(base)
            element = data["elements"]
            choose_random = randint(0, len(element)-1)
            chosen_el = element[choose_random]['Name']
        short = element[0]["Short"]
        self.guess = tk.Label(self, text=chosen_el, font=('Times',20))
        self.guess.grid(row=0,column=2,columnspan=2)
        self.topLabel.config(text="")
        self.infoLine.config(text="")
        self.create_widget()
        selected = (0, len(element)-1)
        if choose_random == selected:
           self.correct = tk.Label(self, text="Correct", font=('Times',20))
           self.correct.grid(row=12, column=5)
        if not choose_random == selected:
           self.not_correct = tk.Label(self, text="Try again", font=('Times',20))
           self.not_correct.grid(row=14, column=5)

    def create_widget(self):
        self.count = tk.Label(self)
        #self.count['command'] = self.update_count
        self.count['text'] = "Celkem pokusů: " + str(self.button_clicks)
        self.count.grid(row=14, column=5, columnspan=10, rowspan=4)

    def update_count(self):
        self.button_clicks += 1

root = tk.Tk()
app = PeriodicTable(root)
app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW") 
root.state('zoomed')
root.minsize(width=1000, height=500)
app.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
app.mainloop()
```

`game.json`:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "elements": [
        {
            "Short": "H",
            "Name": "Vodik",
            "Atomic Number": 1,
            "Atomic Weight": 1.01,
            "State": "Plyny",
            "Categories": ["Nekovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Li",
            "Name": "Lithium",
            "Atomic Number": 3,
            "Atomic Weight": 6.94,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Alkalicke kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Na",
            "Name": "Sodik",
            "Atomic Number": 11,
            "Atomic Weight": 22.99,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Alkalicke kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "K",
            "Name": "Draslik",
            "Atomic Number": 19,
            "Atomic Weight": 39.10,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Alkalicke kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Rb",
            "Name": "Rubidium",
            "Atomic Number": 37,
            "Atomic Weight": 85.47,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Alkalicke kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Cs",
            "Name": "Cesium",
            "Atomic Number": 55,
            "Atomic Weight": 132.91,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Alkalicke kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Fr",
            "Name": "Francium",
            "Atomic Number": 87,
            "Atomic Weight": 223.00,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Alkalicke kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Be",
            "Name": "Beryllium",
            "Atomic Number": 4,
            "Atomic Weight": 9.01,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy alkalickych zemin"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Mg",
            "Name": "Horcik",
            "Atomic Number": 12,
            "Atomic Weight": 24.31,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy alkalickych zemin"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ca",
            "Name": "Vapnik",
            "Atomic Number": 20,
            "Atomic Weight": 40.08,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy alkalickych zemin"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Sr",
            "Name": "Stroncium",
            "Atomic Number": 38,
            "Atomic Weight": 87.62,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy alkalickych zemin"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ba",
            "Name": "Barium",
            "Atomic Number": 56,
            "Atomic Weight": 137.33,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy alkalickych zemin"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ra",
            "Name": "Radium",
            "Atomic Number": 88,
            "Atomic Weight": 226.03,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy alkalickych zemin"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Sc",
            "Name": "Skandium",
            "Atomic Number": 21,
            "Atomic Weight": 44.96,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Y",
            "Name": "Yttrium",
            "Atomic Number": 39,
            "Atomic Weight": 88.91,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "La   >|",
            "Name": "Lanthan",
            "Atomic Number": 57,
            "Atomic Weight": 138.91,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ac   >|",
            "Name": "Actinium",
            "Atomic Number": 89,
            "Atomic Weight": 227.03,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ti",
            "Name": "Titan",
            "Atomic Number": 22,
            "Atomic Weight": 47.90,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Zr",
            "Name": "Zirconium",
            "Atomic Number": 40,
            "Atomic Weight": 91.22,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Hf",
            "Name": "Hafnium",
            "Atomic Number": 72,
            "Atomic Weight": 178.49,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Rf",
            "Name": "Rutherfordium",
            "Atomic Number": 104,
            "Atomic Weight": 261.00,
            "State": "Synteticke",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "V",
            "Name": "Vanad",
            "Atomic Number": 23,
            "Atomic Weight": 50.94,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Nb",
            "Name": "Niobium",
            "Atomic Number": 41,
            "Atomic Weight": 92.91,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ta",
            "Name": "Tantal",
            "Atomic Number": 73,
            "Atomic Weight": 180.95,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Db",
            "Name": "Dubnium",
            "Atomic Number": 105,
            "Atomic Weight": 262.00,
            "State": "Synteticke",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Cr",
            "Name": "Chrom",
            "Atomic Number": 24,
            "Atomic Weight": 51.99,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Mo",
            "Name": "Molybden",
            "Atomic Number": 42,
            "Atomic Weight": 95.94,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "W",
            "Name": "Wolfram",
            "Atomic Number": 74,
            "Atomic Weight": 183.85,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Sg",
            "Name": "Seaborgium",
            "Atomic Number": 106,
            "Atomic Weight": 266.00,
            "State": "Synteticke",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Mn",
            "Name": "Mangan",
            "Atomic Number": 25,
            "Atomic Weight": 178.49,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Tc",
            "Name": "Technecium",
            "Atomic Number": 43,
            "Atomic Weight": 178.49,
            "State": "Synteticke",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Re",
            "Name": "Rhenium",
            "Atomic Number": 75,
            "Atomic Weight": 178.49,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Bh",
            "Name": "Bohrium",
            "Atomic Number": 107,
            "Atomic Weight": 262.00,
            "State": "Synteticke",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Fe",
            "Name": "Zelezo",
            "Atomic Number": 26,
            "Atomic Weight": 55.85,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ru",
            "Name": "Ruthenium",
            "Atomic Number": 44,
            "Atomic Weight": 101.07,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Os",
            "Name": "Osmium",
            "Atomic Number": 76,
            "Atomic Weight": 190.20,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Hs",
            "Name": "Hassium",
            "Atomic Number": 108,
            "Atomic Weight": 265.00,
            "State": "Synteticke",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Co",
            "Name": "Kobalt",
            "Atomic Number": 27,
            "Atomic Weight": 58.93,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Rh",
            "Name": "Rhodium",
            "Atomic Number": 45,
            "Atomic Weight": 102.91,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ir",
            "Name": "Iridium",
            "Atomic Number": 77,
            "Atomic Weight": 192.22,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Mt",
            "Name": "Meitnerium",
            "Atomic Number": 109,
            "Atomic Weight": 266.00,
            "State": "Synteticke",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ni",
            "Name": "Nikl",
            "Atomic Number": 28,
            "Atomic Weight": 58.70,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Pd",
            "Name": "Palladium",
            "Atomic Number": 46,
            "Atomic Weight": 106.40,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Pt",
            "Name": "Platina",
            "Atomic Number": 78,
            "Atomic Weight": 195.09,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Cu",
            "Name": "Med",
            "Atomic Number": 29,
            "Atomic Weight": 63.55,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ag",
            "Name": "Stribro",
            "Atomic Number": 47,
            "Atomic Weight": 107.97,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Au",
            "Name": "Zlato",
            "Atomic Number": 79,
            "Atomic Weight": 196.97,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Zn",
            "Name": "Zinek",
            "Atomic Number": 30,
            "Atomic Weight": 65.37,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Cd",
            "Name": "Kadmium",
            "Atomic Number": 48,
            "Atomic Weight": 112.41,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Hg",
            "Name": "Rtut",
            "Atomic Number": 80,
            "Atomic Weight": 200.59,
            "State": "Kapalne",
            "Categories": ["Prechodne kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "B",
            "Name": "Bor",
            "Atomic Number": 5,
            "Atomic Weight": 10.81,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Polokovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Al",
            "Name": "Hlinik",
            "Atomic Number": 13,
            "Atomic Weight": 26.98,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ga",
            "Name": "Gallium",
            "Atomic Number": 31,
            "Atomic Weight": 69.72,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "In",
            "Name": "Indium",
            "Atomic Number": 49,
            "Atomic Weight": 69.72,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Tl",
            "Name": "Thallium",
            "Atomic Number": 81,
            "Atomic Weight": 204.37,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "C",
            "Name": "Uhlik",
            "Atomic Number": 6,
            "Atomic Weight": 12.01,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Nekovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Si",
            "Name": "Kremik",
            "Atomic Number": 14,
            "Atomic Weight": 28.09,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Polokovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Ge",
            "Name": "Germanium",
            "Atomic Number": 32,
            "Atomic Weight": 72.59,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Polokovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Sn",
            "Name": "Cin",
            "Atomic Number": 50,
            "Atomic Weight": 118.69,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "Pb",
            "Name": "Olovo",
            "Atomic Number": 82,
            "Atomic Weight": 207.20,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Kovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "N",
            "Name": "Dusik",
            "Atomic Number": 7,
            "Atomic Weight": 14.01,
            "State": "Plyny",
            "Categories": ["Nekovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "P",
            "Name": "Fosfor",
            "Atomic Number": 15,
            "Atomic Weight": 30.97,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Nekovy"]
        },
        {
            "Short": "As",
            "Name": "Arsen",
            "Atomic Number": 33,
            "Atomic Weight": 74.92,
            "State": "Pevne",
            "Categories": ["Polokovy"]
        }
    ]
}
```

`elements.json`:
Basically the as the game.json but I couldn't fit it all.

`elements_layout_map.json`:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "map": {
        "H": { "row": 1, "column" : 0 },
        "Li": { "row": 2, "column" : 0 },
        "Na": { "row": 3, "column": 0 },
        "K": { "row": 4, "column": 0 },
        "Rb": { "row": 5, "column": 0 },
        "Cs": { "row": 6, "column": 0 },
        "Fr": { "row": 7, "column": 0 },
        "Be": { "row": 2, "column": 1 },
        "Mg": { "row": 3, "column": 1 },
        "Ca": { "row": 4, "column": 1 },
        "Sr": { "row": 5, "column": 1 },
        "Ba": { "row": 6, "column": 1 },
        "Ra": { "row": 7, "column": 1 },
        "Sc": { "row": 4, "column": 2 },
        "Y": { "row": 5, "column": 2 },
        "La   >|": { "row": 6, "column": 2 },
        "Ac   >|": { "row": 7, "column": 2 },
        "Ti": { "row": 4, "column": 3 },
        "Zr": { "row": 5, "column": 3 },
        "Hf": { "row": 6, "column": 3 },
        "Rf": { "row": 7, "column": 3 },
        "V": { "row": 4, "column": 4 },
        "Nb": { "row": 5, "column": 4 },
        "Ta": { "row": 6, "column": 4 },
        "Db": { "row": 7, "column": 4 },
        "Cr": { "row": 4, "column": 5 },
        "Mo": { "row": 5, "column": 5 },
        "W": { "row": 6, "column": 5 },
        "Sg": { "row": 7, "column": 5 },
        "Mn": { "row": 4, "column": 6 },
        "Tc": { "row": 5, "column": 6 },
        "Re": { "row": 6, "column": 6 },
        "Bh": { "row": 7, "column": 6 },
        "Fe": { "row": 4, "column": 7 },
        "Ru": { "row": 5, "column": 7 },
        "Os": { "row": 6, "column": 7 },
        "Hs": { "row": 7, "column": 7 },
        "Co": { "row": 4, "column": 8 },
        "Rh": { "row": 5, "column": 8 },
        "Ir": { "row": 6, "column": 8 },
        "Mt": { "row": 7, "column": 8 },
        "Ni": { "row": 4, "column": 9 },
        "Pd": { "row": 5, "column": 9 },
        "Pt": { "row": 6, "column": 9 },
        "Cu": { "row": 4, "column": 10 },
        "Ag": { "row": 5, "column": 10 },
        "Au": { "row": 6, "column": 10 },
        "Zn": { "row": 4, "column": 11 },
        "Cd": { "row": 5, "column": 11 },
        "Hg": { "row": 6, "column": 11 },
        "B": { "row": 2, "column": 12 },
        "Al": { "row": 3, "column": 12 },
        "Ga": { "row": 4, "column": 12 },
        "In": { "row": 5, "column": 12 },
        "Tl": { "row": 6, "column": 12 },
        "C": { "row": 2, "column": 13 },
        "Si": { "row": 3, "column": 13 },
        "Ge": { "row": 4, "column": 13 },
        "Sn": { "row": 5, "column": 13 },
        "Pb": { "row": 6, "column": 13 },
        "N": { "row": 2, "column": 14 },
        "P": { "row": 3, "column": 14 },
        "As": { "row": 4, "column": 14 },
        "Sb": { "row": 5, "column": 14 },
        "Bi": { "row": 6, "column": 14 },
        "O": { "row": 2, "column": 15 },
        "S": { "row": 3, "column": 15 },
        "Se": { "row": 4, "column": 15 },
        "Te": { "row": 5, "column": 15 },
        "Po": { "row": 6, "column": 15 },
        "F": { "row": 2, "column": 16 },
        "Cl": { "row": 3, "column": 16 },
        "Br": { "row": 4, "column": 16 },
        "I": { "row": 5, "column": 16 },
        "At": { "row": 6, "column": 16 },
        "He": { "row": 1, "column": 17 },
        "Ne": { "row": 2, "column": 17 },
        "Ar": { "row": 3, "column": 17 },
        "Kr": { "row": 4, "column": 17 },
        "Xe": { "row": 5, "column": 17 },
        "Rn": { "row": 6, "column": 17 },
        ">| Ce": { "row": 11, "column": 3 },
        "Pr": { "row": 11, "column": 4 },
        "Nd": { "row": 11, "column": 5 },
        "Pm": { "row": 11, "column": 6 },
        "Sm": { "row": 11, "column": 7 },
        "Eu": { "row": 11, "column": 8 },
        "Gd": { "row": 11, "column": 9 },
        "Tb": { "row": 11, "column": 10 },
        "Dy": { "row": 11, "column": 11 },
        "Ho": { "row": 11, "column": 12 },
        "Er": { "row": 11, "column": 13 },
        "Tm": { "row": 11, "column": 14 },
        "Yb": { "row": 11, "column": 15 },
        "Lu": { "row": 11, "column": 16 },
        ">| Th": { "row": 12, "column": 3 },
        "Pa": { "row": 12, "column": 4 },
        "U" : { "row": 12, "column": 5 },   
        "Np": { "row": 12, "column": 6 },   
        "Pu": { "row": 12, "column": 7 },   
        "Am": { "row": 12, "column": 8 },   
        "Cm": { "row": 12, "column": 9 },   
        "Bk": { "row": 12, "column": 10 },   
        "Cf": { "row": 12, "column": 11 },   
        "Es": { "row": 12, "column": 12 },   
        "Fm": { "row": 12, "column": 13 },   
        "Md": { "row": 12, "column": 14 },   
        "No": { "row": 12, "column": 15 },   
        "Lr": { "row": 12, "column": 16 }  
    }
}
```

`color_map.json`:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "map": {
        "Alkalicke kovy": "#3895bc",
        "Kovy alkalickych zemin": "#70c2b4",
        "Prechodne kovy": "#b3dbbf",
        "Nekovy": "Light Pink",
        "Kovy": "#74c1cd",
        "Polokovy": "#a1dae3",
        "Halogeny": "#dbb59e",
        "Vzacne plyny": "#986fb3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).